# All analytic bijections from $B(0,1)$ to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, mobius-transformation

I am trying to prove that if $f: B(0,1) \rightarrow B(0,1)$ is an analytic bijection then there exists $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall z\in B(0,1)$  $$f(z)=e^{it}\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$$

I can see that the required form is a Möbius map, so I'm guessing it is necessary to prove it is a Möbius map somehow. I have tried using the Riemann Mapping Theorem, but this doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is  a well known result and you can look at Rudin's RCA for a proof.

Comment: It is an easy consequence of Schwarz lemma as using a Mobius transform you can assume $f(0)=0$ and then with $g$ the inverse, you have $f'(0)g'(0)=1$, while by Schwarz both of those have absolute value at most one, so you must have equality hence $f,g$ are rotations

Comment: The Riemann Mapping Theorem isn't going to help you: it would give you the existence of a Riemann mapping between $B(0,1)$ and $B(0,1)$, which doesn't tell you anything you don't already know.